# Bash mv Command w/ Complex File Names

Tags: windows, bash, powershell

I have a directory containing hundreds of thousands of PDF files with quite complex names. I need to be able to move SOME (not all files) from the directory they're in to another directory. Here is an example of my .sh script that handles it:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/echo "Moving subset 300-399"
# 300-399
/usr/bin/mv *-*-*-3[0-9][0-9]-*-*-*-*.pdf ../destination_folder/
/usr/bin/echo "Moving subset 450-499"
# 450-499
/usr/bin/mv *-*-*-4[5-9][0-9]-*-*-*-*.pdf ../destination_folder/
/usr/bin/echo "Moving subset 500-599"
# 500-599
/usr/bin/mv *-*-*-5[0-9][0-9]-*-*-*-*.pdf ../destination_folder/
```

Because there are so many files and I think that mv is performing an evaluation on every single one, it's taking upwards of two hours to perform the work. This is a script that must be run EVERY day, so I need to find a more efficient way to do the work. Is there a more efficient command I can utilize in a Windows environment or a more efficient way I can evaluate each file in order to speed up the mv process?

Comment: I'm confused, are you looking for a `bash` or `powershell` solution?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I'm looking for the fastest solution available to me in Windows.

Comment: Please keep your question focused on one language. What implementation of `bash` are you using on windows ? Depending on what you have, `powershell` may be faster.

Comment: @Aserre Currently using 4.3.33(1).

Comment: This is not what I meant. Are you using git bash ? cygwin ? wsl 1 / 2 ?

Comment: @Aserre we're using cygwin.

Comment: No matter what solution you use, you'll have trouble if there are that many files in a single folder. Do you have any influence on the process that is putting the files there in the first place? It would be much faster if they were broken up into subfolders - no matter by what criteria, even if you still have to use wildcards like this in each subfolder to find the files you want.

Comment: My answer aside, if you're talking hundreds of thousands of files you should be looking at object storage solutions, or at the *very* least serializing the content in a database. CRUD operations will be far more performant in both than going through a standard file share.

Comment: Is it a one time action? When the first part `*-*-*-` is constant, just use the File Explorer.
How any files will be left after moving? Perhaps is it faster to rename the directory, and move back (to a new created original_folder) the files that you don't want in the destination_folder.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `powershell` will probably be faster as it is native to windows. The difference in speed will be dependent on the implementation of `bash` you are using.

For a pure bash solution, you can try :

```
#!/bin/bash
find /input/folder -regextype posix-extended -regex '^(?:[^-]+-){3}(?:4[5-9]|[35][0-9])[0-9](?:-[^-]+){4}\.pdf$' -exec mv {} /destination/folder +
```

**Explanation :**

- `find /input/folder -regextype posix-extended -regex` :

  - find every file in your input folder that match the regex
- `'^(?:[^-]+-){3}(?:4[5-9]|[35][0-9])[0-9](?:-[^-]+){4}\.pdf$'`

  - the pattern matching your files. More explanations [here](https://regex101.com/r/bYDMkh/1)
- `-exec mv {} /destination/folder +`

  - execute the `mv` command on every file found
  - the `+` symbol means the command will be executed in as few calls as possible, when the `find` command has discovered every file matching the regex

Comment: First, you don't need to backslash the `+` in bash. Second, it does _not_ necessarily mean the `mv` will only be executed once; the files will be chunked into as few `mv` commands as possible, but that may be more than one if there are too many files to fit into a single command.

Comment: @MarkReed [indeed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128559/solving-mv-argument-list-too-long)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `bash` on Windows, you can run each in the background with the `&` suffix and try to parallelize it to achieve better performance. Use the `wait` keyword to wait for the background processes to complete. For example:

```sh
/usr/bin/echo "Moving subset 300-399"
/usr/bin/mv *-*-*-3[0-9][0-9]-*-*-*-*.pdf ../destination_folder/ & # Run this line in the background

# Other async calls

# Wait for background processes to finish
wait
```

---

If you want `PowerShell`, you can use `Start-Job` to run these in the background. To use your 300 subset as an example:

```
Write-Host "Moving subset 300-399"
$mv300jb = Start-Job {
  $sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -File .\*-*-*-3*-*-*-*-*.pdf | Where-Object {
    $_.FullName -match '\\(\w+-){3}3[0-9]{2}(-\w+){4}\.pdf$'
  }

  Move-Item -Path $sourceFiles "..\destination_folder"
}

# Here you would also start other async jobs, assigning $mv400, $mv500, etc. like above
...

# Wait for job to complete
while( $mv300.State -notin 'Completed', 'Failed' ) {
  Start-Sleep 30 # Change this to number of seconds to poll job again
}
```

---

## Honorable mention

A second alternative on Windows would be to use `robocopy.exe` which copies and moves files more performantly than the standard copy and move commands. The `/mt` parameter will make use of multi-threading. Unfortunately, I don't have any `robocopy` examples to share here.

---

## Explaining the regex

> Note: I have since learned that you can use basic character ranges with `Get-ChildItem` and some other PowerShell cmdlets which support globbing. See my edit at the bottom of this answer for more information.

Since asked, here's a breakdown of the .NET regex I used to match on the filename:

`\\(\w+-){3}3[0-9]{2}(-\w+){4}\.pdf$`

- `\\`: Literal `\` character
- `(\w+-)`: Looks for group of one or more `\w` word-characters followed by a `-`

  - `{3}`: Quantifier to match on exactly 3 occurrences of the previous group
- `3[0-9]`: Looks for literal `3` followed by a digit character

  - `{2}`: Quantifier to match on exactly two preceeding digit characters
- `(-\w+)`: Looks for group of one or more `-` characters followed by at least one word-character `\w`.

  - `{4}`: Quantifier to match exactly 4 occurrences of the previous group
- `\.pdf`: Literal `.` character followed by `pdf`
- `$`: End of input/string

At this time of writing I was unaware character ranges can be used with globbing in `Get-ChildItem`, so I resorted to using a regular expression to find the exact number of fields matching the specific number pattern in the 4th field, while ensuring the 8-field filename was intact for any found files.

If you plug this expression into https://regexr.com, it will break the expression down and explain everything better visually than I can here, without making this answer too long.

---

## EDIT

As I learned the other day, you can use character ranges with PowerShell's file matching, though this doesn't work in other contexts within Windows. In my example above the following line can be modified to match letter and number ranges as well without having to use regex. If you take the following code from above:

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -File .\*-*-*-3*-*-*-*-*.pdf | Where-Object {
  $_.FullName -match '\\(\w+-){3}3[0-9]{2}(-\w+){4}\.pdf$'
}
```

we ***can*** use globbing to match on the filename without having to use the `Where-Object` or regular expression, greatly reducing the complexity of this bit:

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -File .\*-*-*-3[0-9][0-9]*-*-*-*-*.pdf
```

Here is the modified code for eschewing the regex in favor of globbing:

```
Write-Host "Moving subset 300-399"
$mv300jb = Start-Job {
  $sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -File .\*-*-*-3*-*-*-*-*.pdf

  Move-Item -Path $sourceFiles "..\destination_folder"
}

# Here you would also start other async jobs, assigning $mv400, $mv500, etc. like above
...

# Wait for job to complete
while( $mv300.State -notin 'Completed', 'Failed' ) {
  Start-Sleep 30 # Change this to number of seconds to poll job again
}
```

The availability of this feature seems to hinge on whether a PowerShell construct is performing the globbing (it works) or if it is native to the Win32 API (does not work). In other words, it seems to be supported by PowerShell but not by other Windows APIs.

Comment: Being new to Powershell, I'm struggling with following your FullName match. Could you describe what you're doing with: '\\(\w+-){3}3[0-9]{2}(-\w+){4}\.pdf$'?

i.e. What's the '$' for? How about the "'\\(\w+-){3}"? etc.

Comment: It's .NET regex. I'll explain it in the answer, just give me a few

Comment: I've updated my answer to break down the regex and recommended a tool for learning regex fairly easily

Comment: Great breakdown of your regex and THANK YOU for sharing that website. That will prove quite useful going forward, I think. I'll be playing around with it this afternoon.

Comment: https://regexr.com is awesome, just note that it only works with ECMAScript (JavaScript) and Perl (PCRE) regex. However, there is enough overlap between the three engines that many expressions will work across all three. If you find an expression you built in regexr doesn't work elsewhere, you have the general pattern you want already, you just need to transpose it to the engine of your choosing.

Comment: FYI, I learned you can use character ranges when pattern matching filenames in PowerShell with `Get-ChildItem`. I've updated my answer with more information about this, which eliminates the need for the regex and greatly simplifies that piece of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth to mention that the duration of these `mv` commands depends on the amount of data of course: the total size of the pdf files in the current directory.

Please, note that `mv` command has at least 2 different behaviors with different performances, depending on the location of the `../destination_folder/` directory:

- `../destination_folder/` and `*.pdf` files on different file systems: the `mv` command is copying the files and then removing them from the source directory.
- `../destination_folder/` and `*.pdf` files on the same file system: only a rename is done which is super fast.

the `df` command can be used to display the `../destination_folder/` directory very nature.

---

Should you could choose the destination directory, then make sure it is located on the same file system: expect a great improvement.

---

In addition, if the `../destination_folder/` directory is located onto a remote server, the duration depends also on the network speed. If this is your situation, then compressing/uncompressing the files while moving should be tested: the performance can be much better.